# how to pass the arguments in SAS (in the form of a macro)

Tags: sas, arguments, sas-macro

In a dataset,I've multiple columns(YAS,YES,YCS,sepstrataname,atrisk etc. ) which i would like to utilize by passing them in to proc template (already built) posted below. NB:have to pass them in the form of a macro, arguments need to be taken based the input values.
[Input data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAxhm.png)

```
ods graphics on/height=8.0in width=10in border=on;
proc template;
define statgraph kmplot;
begingraph;
entrytitle 'Kaplan Meier '/textattrs=(size=8);
layout lattice / rows=3 columndatarange=union rowweights=(0.4 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 
0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05);

layout overlay/yaxisopts=(label='Estimated Survival'
linearopts=(viewmin=0 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(Offsetmin=0.05 Offsetmax=0.05 label='Time (Days) to Death or Discharge' );

stepplot x=time y=survival /name='step' group=stratum;
bandplot limitlower=hw_lcl limitupper=hw_ucl x=time /group=stratum fillattrs=(transparency=0.6);
discretelegend 'step' / location=inside
halign=right valign=top 
across=1 border=true
title='Key' titleborder=true;
endlayout;

/*entry 'sepstrata=0';*/
layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=none
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=YAS0/ markercharacter=sepstrataname0;
endlayout;

layout overlay/ wallDisplay=none yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=YAS0/ markercharacter=atrisk_s0;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=YES0/ markercharacter=events_s0;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=YCS0/ markercharacter=censored_s0;
endlayout;

/*entry 'sepstrata=1';*/

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=none
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=YAS0/ markercharacter=sepstrataname1 ;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=yas1/ markercharacter=atrisk_s1;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=yes1/ markercharacter=events_s1;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=ycs1/ markercharacter=censored_s1;
endlayout;

/*entry 'sepstrata3';*/
layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=none
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=YAS0/ markercharacter=sepstratanameA ;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=yasA/ markercharacter=atrisk_s3;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none  yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=yesA/ markercharacter=events_s3;
endlayout;

layout overlay/wallDisplay=none yaxisopts=(display=(tickvalue)
linearopts=(viewmin=1 viewmax=1))
xaxisopts=(display=none);
scatterplot x=timelist y=ycsA/ markercharacter=censored_3;
endlayout;
endlayout;
endgraph;
end;
```

Like in the code there are 3 arguments passed, for YES , 3 diff columns are produced such as YES1,YES2,YES3, similarly for other variables YCS,YAS,sepstrata.

Comment: Looks like you have step one of macro development, working SAS code.  Step two is identifying the parts that change.  It is hard for us to see where those parts are in your wall of code.  Can you highlight specifically which parts change?

Comment: I think you are looking for dynamic variable in GTL, may this article helps:  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=grstatug&docsetTarget=n1j7cpxoazlv08n1fzajqrq7pyyr.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en